# Приложение отклонено | Google Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-console

Отклонили приложение недавно, но я не могу понять причину. Что за InAppExperience? Откуда это взялось? У меня нет такого png в приложении.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: судя по тому что написано - вы где-то неправильно сформировали начальные данные при старте заполнения в консоли, посмотрите скрин который вам прикрепили, его можно и сюда вставить тоже

Comment: У вас все написано в первой строке - "рейтинг содержимого вашего приложения не верен". Проверяйте контент своего приложения и сделайте корректировку рейтинга на основе его содержимого.

Comment: @Andrew, ты был прав. Я не заметил, что у меня скрин прикриплен. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответы **@Andrew** и **@AndreyMihalev** был правильным. Я не заметил прикрипленного к сообщению файла. Отклонили приложение из-за матерного слова, что несоответствовало указанному возрастному рейтингу.

> **@Andrew**
> судя по тому что написано - вы где-то неправильно сформировали начальные данные при старте заполнения в консоли,
> посмотрите скрин который вам прикрепили, его можно и сюда вставить
> тоже
>
> **@AndreyMihalev** У вас все написано в первой строке - "рейтинг содержимого вашего приложения не верен". Проверяйте контент своего
> приложения и сделайте корректировку рейтинга на основе его
> содержимого.